# Remove duplicated members from vector while maintaining order

Tags: c++

I know this question has been asked a lot, but I could not find the best (the most efficient) way to remove duplicated members (type `double`) from vector while **maintaining 1 copy** and **order of the original vector**.

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried?

Comment: I have a vector of point (defined type) in which probably some points have been inserted twice during process. I want to delete/remove the copied points (only the second copy, I mean I want to have the first copy). and also I want to keep the order of original vector.

Comment: many thanks @Johnsyweb is it the the most efficient way?

Comment: @AliAlamiri: The OP didn't state if they had control over how and where the vector is set up. Otherwise, a set is at least semantically correct.

Comment: @H'H that is what you want.  But what have you tried?  Did you try anything?  Or did you just look at the problem, shrug, and ask here?

Comment: @Yakk for sure I tried it before asking, but since I have some constraints (e.g. keeping original vector order), still am not sure what is the best. I also need to work with the indices of the original vector members afterwords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data was not `double`s, simply doing a pass with an `unordered_set` keeping track of what you have already seen via the `remove_if`-`erase` idiom would work.

`double`s are, however, bad news when checking for equality: two derivations that you may think should produce the same value may generate different results.  A `set` would allow looking for nearby values.  Simply use `equal_range` with a plus minus epsilon instead of `find` to see if there is another value approximetally equal to yours earlier in the `vector`, and use the same `remove` `erase` idiom.

The `remove` `erase` idiom looks like:

```
vec.erase( std::remove_if( vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](double x)->bool{
  // return true if you want to remove the double x
}, vec.end());
```

in C++03 it cannot be done inline.

The lambda above will be called for each element in order, like the body of a loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to/wish to use a vector* then it might be easiest to trap duplicates on insertion - if the point to be inserted is already there, bin it.

Another approach for a really large collection would be to do a sort and search for duplicates after every N insertions, where N is the perfect number of insertions to wait before doing a sort and search for duplicates.  (Calculating N is left as an exercise for the reader.)

Your approach, and the value of N if relevant, depends on the number of elements, how often the array is changed, how often the contents are examined, and the likelihood of duplicates occuring.

(*apparently, vectors are great as their disadvantages lie where modern computers tend to kick butt so hard it doesn't matter, and are blisteringly fast with linear searches.  At least I think that's what Bjarn's saying [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo%E2%80%8E) comparing a vector to a linked list.)